# How do I delete documents from the Amazon cloud?

Tags: amazon, kindle, osx

I used the Mac Amazon 'send to Kindle' application to send a few text files to my iPad. This works, except there's no way to delete files.

The iPad's Kindle app's delete button only deletes files from the device, rather than the cloud. Normally I would go onto Amazon's website to delete the files, but in this case I had unchecked the 'Archive document in your Kindle Library' checkbox. So the documents don't appear on the Kindle webapp.

How do I delete these docs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use an iPad so I can't be sure, but if I haven't ticked the 'archive document in your kindle library' then the document doesn't get sent to the cloud.

So the only copy you need to delete is the one on your iPad.